# Upload file to firebase storage folder with Vue js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Vue js 3 and Firebase 9.
I'm trying to upload images to a specific folder, but I'm having troubles.
When I do this, it renames file to 'product' and uploads it to the main folder.

```
uploadImage(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = storageReference(storage, 'products/');
      uploadBytes(storageRef, file);
    }
```

When I do this, the file goes up with its name but in the main folder.

```
const storageRef = storageReference(storage, file.name);
```

how do I make it go up in the products folder with the name it already has? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will see in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#create_a_reference), you need to create the [`StorageReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.storagereference.md#storagereference_interface) as follows, with the [`ref()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#ref_2) method:

```
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'products/' + file.name);
```

Or with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const storageRef = ref(storage, `products/${file.name}`);
```